# Add items to titlebar in Win32 Forms Application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

How do you add items from the toolbox into the title bar of the window in Visual Studio 2010? I'm currently using a C# Win32 Forms Application. One major example of what I want is Google Chrome, and how its tabs are integrated into the title bar. [image: Tabs in the title bar]

How can I do this in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 0):

There was an old article on [how to do it](http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/41/207281.aspx) in Win Forms.

Or you can just hide the system title bar and create your own (just a control that will behave the same way + what you need) :)

Comment: links die - a summary of the approach used would be great.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however the style that it comes out as is a windows classic type style. Is there anyway to get the title bars and close, minimize, and maximize buttons to inherit the current style along with aero transparency and all that stuff?